# how do i quickly generate scala classes from a set of sql table definitions?

Tags: scala, slick

I have an existing database, and i would like to connect to it with scala/slick.

I'd rather not have to manually write all of the slick classes, to wrap around my tables.

is there a quick way to just read the definitions from the database, from slick? or, possibly, is there another component in the scala standard library or standard toolset, which will do this work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Slick schema generator](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/code-generation.html), you simply need to add this to your `Build.scala`:

```
lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map {
  (dir, cp, r, s) => {
    val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath
    val url = "your db url"
    val jdbcDriver = "dbms drivers"
    val slickDriver = "slick drivers"
    val pkg = "schema"
    toError(r.run("scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg), s.log))
    val fname = outputDir + "/path/to/Tables.scala"
    Seq(file(fname))
  }
}
```

Add the task to the settings:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, Seq()).settings(
  Keys.fork in (Test) := false,
  libraryDependencies := Seq(
    ...
  ),
  slick <<= slickCodeGenTask // register manual sbt command
)
```

And then call `genTables` form SBT, this will create a scala file called `Tables.scala` to the specified path with the whole schema from the database.

[This was the Github example](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example) I looked up the first time.